# Derivation of the Renormalization Group from Renormalized Coupling?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

At page 303 in the book Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur by Blundell and Lancaster, they argue that the renormalization group equation for the coupling $\lambda$ in $\phi^4$ theory can be derived as follows. Firstly, we introduce the renormalized coupling
$$\lambda_R(s_0)  =  \lambda   +\lambda^2 C  \ln \left( \frac{s_0}{\Lambda^2}\right)  + \ldots , $$
and rewrite the matrix element in terms of $\lambda_R$:
$$ iM = - \lambda_R(s_0)    -C \ln \left( \frac{s  }{s_0}\right)  \lambda_R^2(s_0)  + \ldots   \tag{1}  $$ 
For a different scale $s_1$, we find
$$\lambda_R(s_1)  =  \lambda   +\lambda^2 C  \ln \left( \frac{s_1}{\Lambda^2}\right)  + \ldots , $$
$$ iM = - \lambda_R(s_1)    -C \ln \left( \frac{s  }{s_1}\right)  \lambda_R^2(s_1)  + \ldots \tag{2}  $$ 
They then argue that by "subtracting" it follows that
$$\lambda_R(s_1)  = \lambda_R(s_0)  +C \ln \left( \frac{s_1 }{s_0}\right)  \lambda_R^2(s_0)  + \ldots \tag{3}$$
I'm failing to see why this should be true. If we subtract Eq. 2 from Eq. 1 we find a term of the form
$$ -C \ln \left( \frac{s  }{s_1}\right)  \lambda_R^2(s_1)+C  \ln \left( \frac{s_0}{\Lambda^2}\right)\lambda_R^2(s_0)  $$
which is not equal to the one in Eq. 3 unless $\lambda_R^2(s_0) = \lambda_R^2(s_1)$.

*Am I missing something or is the derivation shown here wrong?*

Comment: In eq.(2), why should the first term on the RHS depend on $s_0$ instead of $s_1$?

Comment: @Jon that was a typo, thanks!

Comment: You subtracted Eq. 1 from Eq. 2 incorrectly. The answer starts with the answer they give you and a term proportional to $\lambda_R^2 (s_0) -\lambda_R^2 (s_1)$, which, by above, you *must* appreciate is of *higher order* in $\lambda$, cubic. can you work it out?

Comment: @CosmasZachos unfortunately no. I still can’t see it. Any further hint would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After subtraction you get
$$
\lambda_R(s_1)=\lambda_R(s_0)+C\ln\left(\frac{s}{s_0}\right)\lambda_R^2(s_0)-C\ln\left(\frac{s}{s_1}\right)\lambda_R^2(s_1)+O\left(\lambda_R^3\right).
$$
This is an implicit equation for $\lambda_R(s_1)$ that can be solved iteratively. Then,
$$
\lambda_R(s_1)=\lambda_R(s_0)+C\ln\left(\frac{s}{s_0}\right)\lambda_R^2(s_0)-C\ln\left(\frac{s}{s_1}\right)\left[\lambda_R(s_0)+C\ln\left(\frac{s}{s_0}\right)\lambda_R^2(s_0)+\dots\right]^2+\ldots.
$$
From this, neglecting powers higher than 2 of the coupling, you are able to recover the book's result.