# Is there some truth to the often told story that the running of couplings is the result of screening through virtual particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

It's a [well established fact](https://www.science20.com/a_quantum_diaries_survivor/run_alpha_strong_run-150633) that coupling parameters changes with the energy scale at which we probe a given process:

[image]

A [popular way](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/raby.1/unification.physics.today.pdf) to explain this phenomenon goes as follows. Particles are surrounded by clouds of virtual particles which screen (or anti-screen) the bare charge, analogous to what happens in a dielectric material.

[image]

As we probe the process at higher energies, we start to see more and more of these virtual electrons and thus the net charge that we observe becomes weaker.

---

Virtual particles are, of course, a controversial topic. But I was wondering if there is some truth to this story?

Answer (score 1):

Basically I think that your explanation works. I would add the following intuition about the RG - following Wilson (his [Nobel lecture](https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/06/wilson-lecture-2.pdf) is a wonderful read), I think it is useful to think of the RG as averaging over length-scales. For long wave-lengths (corresponding to low-energy), we average over large distances, meaning that together with the particle we "pick up" a lot of the interactions around it, the virtual particles that interact with it constantly etc. Therefore we indeed get screening. At short wave-lengths (=high energy) we average only over the very vicinity of the particle, therefore getting less screening effects and having a direct access to the "bare" charge (which is just the coupling constant it has with the photons).

Answer (score 0):

To give some context for what I have in mind, here's the best answer I came up with myself. Corrections, comments and better answers would be much appreciated.

The proper mathematical context to discuss this question are the renormalization group equations. For example, in  [$\phi^4$-theory we have](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/514654/derivation-of-the-renormalization-group-from-renormalized-coupling): 
$$ \lambda_R(s_1)  = \lambda_R(s_0)  +C \ln \left( \frac{s_1 }{s_0}\right)  \lambda_R^2(s_0)  + \ldots $$

The idea is that we choose some reference scale $s_0$. By definition, the process is at this scale completely described by the simple single-vertex diagram with coupling $\lambda_R(s_0)$ at the vertex. But as soon as we probe the process at a different scale $s_1$, we must take corrections into account which are described by the renormalization group equation. Formulated differently, if we consider a perturbative expansion in the renormalized coupling at reference scale $s_0$, $\lambda_R(s_0)$, we only describe the process completely by the simple single vertex diagram at scale $s_0$. At any other scale $s_1$, we must take corrections due to additional diagrams into account. In this sense, the effects of virtual particles (which correspond to lines in the loop) become important at higher energy scales.

[image]

In particular, higher order correction become more and more important as we move farther away from $s_0$. This is a result of the logarithmic dependence on $s_1/s_0$. In this sense, the effects of virtual particles become even more important at higher energy scales. And, as a result, the charge becomes, at least in this case, more anti-screened.