# What is screening in Quantum Field Theory and how does it influence the strength of interactions in QCD?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, vacuum, interactions, virtual-particles

Question is fairly straight to the point. In particular, how does it influence the strength of particle interactions?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to come up with a simplified example for electrons,  and failed. please see [Particles, fluctuations and the quantum vacuum: is this right?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/444267/particles-fluctuations-and-the-quantum-vacuum-is-this-right) for the real answer.

[Is there some truth to the often told story that the running of couplings is the result of screening through virtual particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/515024/is-there-some-truth-to-the-often-told-story-that-the-running-of-couplings-is-the) is also worth reading, as is the wikipedia article on virtual particles.

As an aside, my original answer was a non-expert's crude description of the processes discussed in the "running of couplings" answer linked above, which was provided by an expert. I'll let him handle the slings and arrows that always seem to get tossed around during arguments about whether or not virtual particles themselves have any real existence.